# how to compare arrays and create new array that matches with array a?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I want to match two arrays if array `b` contains string values of array a i want to create new array , with below code its pushing all objects from array b. How can i push only object that matches ?

ctrl.js

```
 var a = ["standard","industry","4578595"]
 var b = [{file:"server.log",value:"lorem ipsum industry standard 4578595"}, {file:"server.log",value:"lorem ipsum industry standadr"},{file:"server.log",value:"lorem ipsum industry"}];
 var finalyArray = [];
 function compareArrays() {   
     for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         for (z = 0; z < a.length; z++) {
             if (a[i] === b[z]) {
                 finalArray.push(b[z]);
                 console.log(finalArray); 
             }
         }
     }
}

compareArrays();
```

Comment: I think you're missing a quote...

Comment: that was just typo, results is same

Comment: No items in `a` match any of the items in `b`. First you need to define what "match" means in this context

Comment: well, define 'matches' for your use case. You code would work fine if you were comparing two arrays of the same type, but you are comparing an array of strings to an array of objects so nothing will match with `===`.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, `(z = 0; z < a.length; z++)` should be `(z = 0; z < b.length; z++)`, but as others have said nothing is 'matching' in this instance

Comment: yeah, good spot.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would guess you mean all (or maybe just some - it really isn't clear) the strings in `a` must appear in `b[z].value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use nested loops and normal iteration.

Array filtering is cleaner and quite suitable for this:

```js
const a = ["standard","industry","4578595"]
const b = [{file:"server.log",value:"lorem ipsum industry standard 4578595"}, {file:"server.log",value:"lorem ipsum industry standadr"},{file:"server.log",value:"lorem ipsum industry"}];

const matchingCondition = ({ itemB, itemA }) => itemB.value.includes(itemA);

// filter all items from B that satisfy a matching condition with at least one item from A
const matches = b.filter(
  itemB => a.some(
    itemA => matchingCondition({ itemB, itemA })
  )
);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: if i just have one value in `a` for example `["standard"]` i see error ` a.some is not a function`

Comment: If you have `a = ["standard"]`, then `a.some` has to be a function because arrays the method `some` on their prototoype (assuming prototypes werent' altered in some way). Perhaps you have `a = "standard"` instead? So a string, not an array. In that case you would skip the `some` call and pass `a` directly into matching condition.

Comment: i will have both cases user input can have one or multiple keywords , can you edit your answer to make it work.

Comment: It's trivial to make that work - you should make some effort as well :)

Comment: I am not familiar with ES6 also i already spent 3 hours want to resolve this issue. anyways thanks for the help let me see

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: just noticed you have implemented if one item from A satisfied , in my case all items A has to match with B.

Comment: You can use the `every` function instead of `some` in that case.

Comment: thanks that worked for that case , still trying to figure out in case if string array contains one value why it breaks now its breaking on `searchStr.every(function (itemA)` is not a function

Comment: Use direct comparison instead of an array method,  so `YOUR_ITEM === searchStr`. Think about it, you have a single string so there's no need to check every element in the string, in fact it's not even clear what "every" means for a string (there is no `every` method on the String prototype), you just need to compare your item to that single string.

Comment: but its still coming as an array string why filter method is not working

Comment: sorry but another problem is its creating duplicate records :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    // return a subset array of b, which contains all the strings of array a 

    var a = ["standard","industry","4578595"]
    var b = [
      {file:"server.log",value:"lorem ipsum industry standard 4578595"}, 
      {file:"server.log",value:"lorem ipsum industry standadr"},
      {file:"server.log",value:"lorem ipsum 4578595 industry"}];

    function filterArray(a,b) {
      var aLen = a.length;
      var bLen = b.length;
      var filterArray = []

      // if a is empty it should return empty array
      if (!aLen){
        return filterArray;
      }

      for(var i = 0; i< bLen; i++) {
        var bValuesArray = b[i].value.split(" ");
        var bValuesLength = bValuesArray.length;
        var addObject = 0;

        for(var j=0; j< aLen; j++) {
           for(var k=0; k <bValuesLength; k++ ){
              if(a[j] === bValuesArray[k]){
                addObject++;
                continue;
              }
           }
        }
        // add if all elements of a are present in b array
        if(addObject === aLen) {
          filterArray.push(b[i]);
        }
      }

      return filterArray;
    };

    console.log(filterArray(a,b));
```